# Writing to a file on GitHub through Heroku

Tags: python, github, heroku, discord, discord.py

I have created a Discord bot with discord.py. I'm using Heroku for hosting and all of my files are uploaded on GitHub. I also have .txt files here with data of users - the problem is that I can't overwrite them, just read them. Is there any better way where to store data (to have complete access to them)? If yes, its some database, I think. So if I upload database file to GitHub, instead of .txt files, will I have full access from Heroku to them? (read + write)

Thanks.

Comment: Generally the application and the database are kept separate.  You won't back up your database into your repository.  [See this page about getting started with Postgres on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql).  [If your bot does anything with the voice part of `discord.py`, heroku is probably a bad fit.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49806427/heroku-deployment-libopus-not-found)

Comment: My bot does not work with voice part of discord.py, its just for text. So - what is the best way for me? How to use database if not uploaded on GitHub, as the application is?