# Python Discord Bot hosted on Heroku doesn't play audio

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, bots, discord.py

I'm building something like music bot and I decided to host it on heroku. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work properly. Everything works fine, bot connects to a voice channel, but I can't hear any audio playing from bot. Yesterday I got an error (logs from heroku):

```
2020-08-06T15:13:45.003027+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in on_ready
2020-08-06T15:13:45.004547+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-06T15:13:45.004619+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
2020-08-06T15:13:45.004620+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2020-08-06T15:13:45.004623+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "papaj.py", line 58, in on_ready
2020-08-06T15:13:45.004624+00:00 app[worker.1]:     voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(path), after=lambda x: endSong(guild, path))
2020-08-06T15:13:45.004641+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/voice_client.py", line 411, in play
2020-08-06T15:13:45.004642+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.encoder = opus.Encoder()
2020-08-06T15:13:45.004644+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/opus.py", line 231, in __init__
2020-08-06T15:13:45.004644+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise OpusNotLoaded()
2020-08-06T15:13:45.004672+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.opus.OpusNotLoaded
```

But today I somehow fixed it and I'm not getting any error messages, **but audio is still not playing from bot.** It looks like this:

```
2020-08-06T15:27:50.232782+00:00 app[worker.1]: [youtube] 1dOt_VcbgyA: Downloading webpage
2020-08-06T15:27:50.736856+00:00 app[worker.1]: [download] Destination: Wykop - Barka (Electro Version)-1dOt_VcbgyA.webm
2020-08-06T15:27:50.875706+00:00 app[worker.1]: [ffmpeg] Destination: Wykop - Barka (Electro Version)-1dOt_VcbgyA.mp3
2020-08-06T15:27:57.656852+00:00 app[worker.1]: Deleting original file Wykop - Barka (Electro Version)-1dOt_VcbgyA.webm (pass -k to keep)
```

After that it just stops. **(When I run it on my computer everything works fine.)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I solved it
(when I tried to run it on my computer I got an error, but on Heroku it works perfect).

**I added this to my script:**

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util
 
print("ctypes - Find opus:")
a = ctypes.util.find_library('opus')
print(a)
 
print("Discord - Load Opus:")
b = discord.opus.load_opus(a)
print(b)
 
print("Discord - Is loaded:")
c = discord.opus.is_loaded()
print(c)
```

Remember to put it before anything linked to audio (the best option is to paste it at the beginning).
[Source](https://pastebin.com/U4VsB8XF)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55920177/14058810

"According to the discord.py docs you should not need it on a windows environnement, which is maybe why it worked on your local machine and not on heroku (which is unix based)."