# I'm getting an error while running discord.py: discord.opus.OpusNotLoaded

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a music bot and everything seems to be working until I try to play a song and it downloads and fails. Please help

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient
import random
from random import choice
import youtube_dl
import os



#Setting up client
prefix = '.'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix)
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url : str):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Wait for the current playing music to end or use the 'stop' command")
        return

    voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name='General')
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))


@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


@client.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.pause()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Currently no audio is playing.")


@client.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_paused():
        voice.resume()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The audio is not paused.")


@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    voice.stop()



#Running client on server
client.run('TOKEN')
```

The exact Error raised is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OpusNotLoaded:

Comment: **Take a look here:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919924/discord-py-command-raised-an-exception-opusnotloaded

Comment: Doesn't work, tried everything from there