# replit fails to install/use discord.opus

Tags: discord, discord.py, replit, opus

Grettings.
i've had a discord music bot since 2 years ago and it was working perfectly fine back then.but now when i try to play something i get the error below:
  `File "/home/runner/Goorbebot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 238, in wrapped raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OpusNotLoaded:`

and when i try to load opus it says that i don't have the package.
also when i looked it up, replit is supposed to have it by default and i can't figure out why it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a unix based system, try using `discord.opus.load_opus()`

Windows and Mac should not require this, I assume you're using repl because of the /home/runner

Repl runs on a UNIX based system as well

Credit: [Opus Not Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55920177/23227537)

Comment: `TypeError: load_opus() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`also when i try using libopus or libopus.so as the argument the system can't find them

Comment: Maybe try `apt-get install libopus0`